# Trying to retrieve all the Metadata components in VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, retrieve

I have tried to [retrieve all the Metadata components](https://www.pablogonzalez.io/how-to-retrieve-your-entire-salesforce-metadata-with-2-commands/) from a Production org in VS Code successfully in the past by using the below command.

**sf project generate manifest --from-org   --name=allMetadata --output-dir manifest**

But, now it gives the below error:

*C:\Users**************\AppData\Local\sf\client\2.11.8-c9872b8\node_modules@salesforce\source-deploy-retrieve\lib\src\resolve\connectionResolver.js:59
throw new core_1.SfError(messages.getMessage('error_could_not_infer_type', [component.fullName]), 'TypeInferenceError', [messages.getMessage('suggest_type_more_suggestions')]);

^
SfError [TypeInferenceError]: _Default: Could not infer a metadata type*

Has anyone faced the same issue? If yes, is there a resolution? I have attached the images for the

1. VS Code version[image]
2. Salesforce Extension pack version[image]
3. Salesforce CLI Integration version[image]
4. SF CLI Version[image]

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Soham